# Using comboBox from another form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I want to use comboBox1 which is in Form1 and display it in a MessageBox after a button click in form 2. In Form2 I used:

```
    MessageBox.Show(Form.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

I get an error saying that comboBox1 is inaccessable due to a protection level. Is there a way that I can get it to be public? I also tried assigning comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() to a string variable in Form1 and using it in the MessageBox in Form2 but it didn't seem to work either. Is there any other way that I can get this to work?

Here is the rest of my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            string[] numbers= { i.ToString() };
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(numbers);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Form = new Form2();
        Form.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Form = new Form1();
        MessageBox.Show(Form.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); //Here is my error
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do it like this:

Inside `Form1` you instantiate the `Form2` like this new `Form2(this)`, i.e. you are passing the `Form1` itself, and thus you should be able to use any public variable/property of `Form1` in `Form2`.

A more preferable way would be to store the `selecteditem` of `Form1` in some `global scope` from where you can access it in `Form2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the ComboBox a property of the form like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ComboBox Combo1 { get { return this.comboBox1; } }
   ...
}
```

and then it would work. However, you would have to tweak your code a little bit because you need to 1) show the form and 2) the ComboBox will have nothing selected right away, so you will get another exception, so you can force a selection. All of the code would look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form1 Form = new Form1();
    Form.Show();
    Form.Combo1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    MessageBox.Show(Form.Combo1.SelectedItem.ToString()); //Here is my error
}
```

Comment: But you're showing the Form1 again from Form2 which could be really confusing.

Comment: I don't know what he is trying to accomplish, but that's what he is asking for...

Comment: The Form.Combo1.SelectedIndex = 0; is returning only the first value of the combobox and not the selected value. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: @meau94 that was only an example. If there is a selected item already you do not need to set up the SelectedIndex of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: In the designer, every control has a property called `Modifiers`, where you set if it's `private`, `public`, etc. Just change it and it will become visible outside of your form.

Now, in your code for Form2, you're creating a *new* Form1, not just accessing the previous instance that created Form2 to begin with. That will show the user a second Form1 which I guess is not what you wanted to do.
The most naive way to workaround this would be to provide Form2 with a public property that will hold the Form1 which created it, and use that to access the combo:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 ParentForm {get; set;}

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.ParentForm.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

In Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.ParentForm = this;
    form.Show();
}
```